# How can I avoid manually typing text with a certain pattern in IDEA , like pic1 ,pic2 ,pic3...picn

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to import all the photos at once like this, and each photo name has the same regularity, I think whether IDEA has some tools to deal with this kind of problem. The manual input is really too annoying, is there any good way to deal with it
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can be done with multiple carets + [String Manipulation](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162-string-manipulation) plugin:

- put the caret after `images/`, add [multiple carets](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2021.1/multicursor.html#add-delete-clone-caret) to edit all `src` paths simultaneously, enter `leftico01`

```
<div class="title"><img src="images/leftico01" alt="img"></div>
<div class="title"><img src="images/leftico01" alt="img"></div>
<div class="title"><img src="images/leftico01" alt="img"></div>
<div class="title"><img src="images/leftico01" alt="img"></div>
```

- with multiple carets positioned after `1`, use **Edit > String Manipulation > Increment/Decrement... > Increment Duplicates**

This would result in

```
<div class="title"><img src="images/leftico01" alt="img"></div>
<div class="title"><img src="images/leftico02" alt="img"></div>
<div class="title"><img src="images/leftico03" alt="img"></div>
<div class="title"><img src="images/leftico04" alt="img"></div>
```